# "Yaamod p'loni ben p'loni... chazak"?

Tags: minhag, torah-service, ashkenazi, provenance

The last *ole* (person called to the Torah) (besides the *maftir*) of *Vaychi*, *P'kude*, *B'chukosay*, and *Mas'e* is, in my experience, called using the formula "*yaamod p'loni ben p'loni sh'vii chazak*", with *chazak* added at the end.

In some instances, a bridegroom called to the Torah on the *Shabas* before his wedding, or a boy his first *Shabas* of *bar mitzva*-hood, is also called as "*yaamod p'loni ben p'loni maftir* [or *r'vii* or whatever] *chazak*", with *chazak* added at the end.

- What is the provenance of these customs?
- What is their reason/basis?

And anything that can be said about their incidence/currency (who has these customs?) would also be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen all of the above, and seen the life cycle ones corrected for when forgotten by the _gabai_.

Comment: I bet the life-cycle ones are "borrowed" form the end-of-the-sefer ones to make them seem more important.

Comment: Custom recorded [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=46&hilite=), but no reason or provenance given.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZN6h03C5Lmk

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the book, we say "chazak chazak v'nitchazek".  This is presumably the reason that the maftir or 7th aliya is called up as "chazak".  I suspect the reason for calling up life-cycle one's this way is, as @doubleAA says above, in order to make them seem more important.