# When do we call someone up as "Chazak"?

Tags: torah-service

Sometimes I hear people being called up as *Yaamod, Ploni ben Ploni Reviyi **Chazak***.

Most of the time there is something interesting about the Aliya or Oleh. Is there any hard and fast rule when to say *Chazak* or not?

Comment: Dupe by msh210 somewhere

Comment: @doubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13331/yaamod-ploni-ben-ploni-chazak